# how to avoid queries in looping

Tags: java, sql, json, oracle

In my project i configured menu like below

```
Menu Group Id Menu ID Parent Menu Id  Menulevel     Name              Action   GroupName
      1         1             1          1        Home                a.htm      mainuser
      2         2             1          1       Report               b.htm      mainuser
      3         3             1          2      Customer              c.htm      mainuser
      4         4             2          2      Merchant              d.htm      mainuser
      5         5             1          2     Corporate              e.htm      mainuser
```

I want to generate below json from the above table

```
 {
  "menuname" :  "home",
  "action" :  "    a.htm,
  "hasChild" :  "   true ,
  "childlist" :  [  
  {
     "menuname" :  "Customer",
     "action" :  "c.htm",
     "hasChild" :  "false",
  },

  {
     "menuname" :  "Corporate",
     "action" :  "e.htm",
     "hasChild" :  "false",
  }
  ]
  }
```

To genrate above json first i am fetching parent menu's then i am looping each parent menu using that parent id am getting submenu.

```
select * from menugroup where GroupName='mainuser' and Menulevel=1
      for each parent menu
        select * from menugroup where GroupName='mainuser' and Precedence=1
```

Is their any way to avoid second query??
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

you could probably go with a `connect by` as of:

```
select * from menugroup
start with menu_group_id = parent_group_id
connect by prior menu_group_id = parent_group_id and prior menu_group_id != menu_group_id
where groupname = 'mainuser'.
```

This would grant you your data as a hierarchy and would resolve a need for a nested loop.

Comment: It returns only parent menus not child menu